# Relative Selectors in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm wondering if there are "relative" selectors in Selenium like the `ele.css` selector in Scrapy. For instance, in Scrapy you can do this:

```
for li in response.css('ul.rows li p.result-info'):
    lnk = li.css('a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    prc = li.css('span.result-meta span.result-price::text').extract_first()
    sqf = li.css('span.result-meta span.housing::text').extract_first()
    loc = li.css('span.result-meta span.result-hood::text').extract_first()
    objct = {
        'lnk': lnk,
        'prc': prc,
    }
    if sqf:
        chunk = sqf.split()
        objct['sqf'] = chunk[len(chunk)-1]
    if loc:
        objct['loc'] = loc
    yield objct
```

**Is it possible to do something like this in Selenium?**

Right now I've been using the following code, which obviously creates problems since the paths aren't relevant. Instead of scraping, say, all of the details for each item one item at a time (i.e. price, size, color for item A, then price, size, color for item B, then price, size, color for item C, so on and so forth), I'm stuck? scraping one detail for all items (i.e. price for item A, item B, and item C, then size for item A, item B, item C) like in the following code.

```
discoverable_cards = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="discoverableCard"]')
product_type = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="discoverableCard-body"]/div[1]/span')
titles = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-title")]')
descriptions = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-description")]')
categories = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-category")]')
balances = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-balance")]')
currencies = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-currencyCode")]')
percentages = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-percent")]')
statuses = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-formattedDate")] | //div[contains(@class, "discoverableCard-InDemandBottomLabel")]')
```

## A Sample of the HTML (and an example of what I mean)

```
<discoverable-card ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns track by campaign.clickthroughUrl" ng-click="cardClick()" gogo-test="card_1" lazy-load-image="true" discoverable="campaign" iggref="pica" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><div class="discoverableCard">
  <a in-view="$inview &amp;&amp; trackImpression()" ng-click="clickDiscoverable($event)" href="/projects/tastetro-spice-system-vegan/coming_soon/pica" gogo-test="card">
    <div class="discoverableCard-image lazyloaded" ng-class="{'lazyload': lazyLoadImage}" id="discoverableCard-image" data-bgset="https://c1.iggcdn.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_273,w_273/cvuilsvvspmvmxhdynup.jpg" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://c1.iggcdn.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_273,w_273/cvuilsvvspmvmxhdynup.jpg&quot;);">
    <picture style="display: none;"><source data-srcset="https://c1.iggcdn.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_273,w_273/cvuilsvvspmvmxhdynup.jpg" sizes="273px" srcset="https://c1.iggcdn.com/indiegogo-media-prod-cld/image/upload/c_fill,f_auto,h_273,w_273/cvuilsvvspmvmxhdynup.jpg"><img alt="" class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded" data-sizes="auto" data-parent-fit="cover" sizes="273px"></picture></div>
    <div class="discoverableCard-body">
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isCampaign() --><div ng-if="viewModel.isCampaign()" class="discoverableCard-type discoverableCard-type--crowdfunding ng-scope">
           <span class="discoverableCard-type--crowdfundingLabel ng-binding" ng-bind="i18n.t('discoverable_card.type_label_campaign')">Funding</span>
           <!-- ngIf: !user && viewModel.isSaveForLaterCompatible() --><div user-auth-modal="" ng-if="!user &amp;&amp; viewModel.isSaveForLaterCompatible()" ng-click="toggleSavedForLater($event)" banner="i18n.t('discoverable_card.auth_modal_banner')" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><span class="campaignLoginModal" ng-click="openModal()" ng-transclude="">
             <span class="iggPopoverHtml ng-binding ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" ng-class="{ 'entreTooltip' : entre }" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml" igg-popover="" placement="top" aria-label="Save for later" role="img" aria-disabled="false" html="<svg><use xlink:href='#icon-icon-follow'></use></svg>"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-icon-follow"></use></svg></span>
           </span><user-auth-modal banner="banner" status="status" class="ng-isolate-scope"></user-auth-modal></div><!-- end ngIf: !user && viewModel.isSaveForLaterCompatible() -->
           <!-- ngIf: user && viewModel.isSaveForLaterCompatible() && !viewModel.isSavedForLater() -->
           <!-- ngIf: user && viewModel.isSaveForLaterCompatible() && viewModel.isSavedForLater() -->
      </div><!-- end ngIf: viewModel.isCampaign() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isProduct() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isOffering() -->
      <div class="discoverableCard-title ng-binding discoverableCard-lineClamp2" ng-class="::viewModel.titleClampClass()" gogo-test="title" ng-bind="::viewModel.discoverable.title">TasteTro Spice System</div>
      <div class="discoverableCard-description ng-binding discoverableCard-lineClamp3" ng-class="viewModel.descriptionClampClass()" ng-bind="::viewModel.discoverable.tagline">An intelligent spice rack that delivers mouthwatering spice blends at the touch of a button.</div>
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isOffering() -->
      <div class="discoverableCard-category ng-binding" gogo-test="category" ng-click="clickCategory($event)" ng-bind="::viewModel.discoverable.category">Food &amp; Beverages</div>
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.showCrowdFundingProgress() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isStandardCampaign() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isInDemandCampaign() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isPreLaunchCampaign() --><div ng-if="viewModel.isPreLaunchCampaign()" class="discoverableCard-preLaunchBulletPoint ng-binding ng-scope" ng-bind="::viewModel.discoverable.bulletPoint">Register to get access to TasteTro's secret perks!</div><!-- end ngIf: viewModel.isPreLaunchCampaign() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isPreLaunchCampaign() --><div ng-if="viewModel.isPreLaunchCampaign()" class="discoverableCard-LaunchingSoon ng-scope">
        <svg-icon icon="icon-rocket" class="ng-isolate-scope"><svg class="iconLaunchingRocket" aria-label="Rocket Icon" role="img" aria-disabled="false">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-rocket"></use>
</svg>
</svg-icon>
        <span class="discoverableCard-LaunchingSoonLabel ng-binding" ng-bind="::i18n.t('discoverable_card.launching_soon_label')">Launching Soon</span>
      </div><!-- end ngIf: viewModel.isPreLaunchCampaign() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isProduct() -->
      <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isOffering() -->
    </div>
    <!-- ngIf: viewModel.isOffering() -->
  </a>
</div>
</discoverable-card>
```

In the above example, what I would like to do is, say, select `discoverable-card` (i.e. `discoverable_card = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//discoverable-card'`), and then make further selections like so: `dc_child = discoverable_card.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'relative/path/to/child')`.

Comment: Can you share HTML (at least simplified) and required output?

Comment: @Andersson i'm not looking for a particular type of output, so to speak. i'm looking for a way to select an element, and then select children elements relative to the element which was selected initially, if that makes sense? i can def include some HTML, give me a moment tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select child/descendant element of already defined element as below:

```
discoverable_cards = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//discoverable-card')
for card in discoverable_cards:
    dc_child = card.find_element(By.XPATH, './relative/path/to/child')
```

Note that you should specify dot in the beginning of child (`./`)/descendant (`.//`) locator to point on current `card` element

Comment: because `.` selects the current node, correct? what would be the point of using `.//` when you could just reference it with `card`?

Comment: If to use *any other* selector, yes, it will work just as `card.find_element()`, but in case of XPath you should also specify a dot to point on context